# How do I implement user-customisable permissions on user-generated subsites?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm making a website in which users will be able to link up to an external server and monitor it using my site. These are accessed through site/Server/[Server-Name]/PageName which is forwarded to a ServerController which then loads the relevant page as expected.

Unfortunately, there's a complication in this whereby users need to be able to add other users to their service and allow them a number of permissions (Which are all pre-defined), and as a result of this, I can't think how to implement permissions at all. I'd rather not roll my own if possible, since the main reason I transitioned from PHP to ASP.NET is for the massive automation on features like this. Note that since one user can be tied to multiple services with varying permissions, a single permission set per person is not possible.

I was wondering if there's any facilities built in that I could use to implement this permissions facility, or whether I would have to roll my own. Are there perhaps any built-in features I could adapt? I've got no idea what direction to go in so I was hoping someone with expertise or experience in these systems may be able to help.

Comment: Are you using a Role provider?

Comment: I haven't started implementing the solution since I can't decide how to implement it, so I'm open to any ideas. Just as a sidenote, I'm using the most recent versions of MVC/.NET/etc.

Comment: How many sub-sites are you thinking about?  Will any user have access to multiple sites at the same time (www.mywebsite.com/subsite1 and www.mywebsite.com/subsite2)?

Comment: There won't be a hard limit, per se. They'll be able to register one themselves and add other users to it with permissions they decide upon. They can then add or remove users and adjust their permissions at any given time. They'll be able to use the same account to administrate multiple, too, which is I suppose where using one permissions set trips up

Comment: This is more complicated than you might think. I would do a bunch of research and trying some implementations before waiting for somebody on SO to present a solution to you.

Comment: Ah :( I guess I figured that would be the case. Thanks for the advice, though.